# How to divide the count number in with Kusto in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I have a log query in Azure that looks something like this:

```
table
    | where timestamp > ago(30min) 
    | count
```

What I want is to divide that count with a number, for example "5". I tried the query below but it throws an exception. How can I do this in another way?

```
table
    | where timestamp > ago(30min) 
    | count / 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to project it first because `count` is an operator and not an ordinary number or function like `count()` :

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(30min) 
| count
| project Count / 5
```

An other way is using the `count()` function:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(30min) 
| summarize count() / 5
```